# MS Teams: Collaboration with Save As Option

Tags: microsoft-teams

So I have an Excel file that functions as a report folks fill out daily. I'd like to have it as it's own tab, but when they're done filling it out, they FILE > SAVE AS to the Team files. Basically a quick access tab, where they would then save each file to a folder that functions as an archive.

Is this possible? If so, what am I missing during setup?

Thanks!

Comment: The the Excel file is actually kind of a "template", rather than the actual final spreadsheet?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow yes, exactly! (It seems a bit complicated to put it as a Form tab though; but I'm also pretty new to teams so Im open to suggestions.)

Answer (score 0):

So I guess it's kind of possible to do what you're wanting, maybe by hosting the spreadsheet somewhere else (not in the general "Shared" folder in the Team's  SharePoint site), and making it Read Only so users have to save it elsewhere, but for something like this, it really sounds like more of a "form" type of scenario, and I'd suggest looking to a more standard form solution. Maybe look into Microsoft Forms, Power Apps, or even [Forms for Excel](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms-blog/forms-for-excel-new-experience-for-excel-survey-in-office-365/ba-p/109195) (Also part of Office 365, but stores the final result into a spreadsheet in your OneDrive). It depends on the Excel and what it's doing, of course, but this is assuming it's a reasonably simple form. If not, post a comment here with more information and I can update this answer / suggest alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for this info! I'll check out those options you mentioned and see if those may work better! I'm wanting ease of access, but also a co-located spot to open and save them. Sounds like Forms for Excel may work best!

Comment: sure thing, glad to help. I don't think you've got enough points to "upvote" but please "mark as answer" so others can benefit if they have a similar query.